# Почему dynamic_cast считается плохой практикой, и когда он действительно необходим?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

Я пытаюсь найти доказательства того, что в некоторых случаях `dynamic_cast` может быть полезен, но информации по этой теме почему-то крайне мало.

Например, недавно я столкнулся с одной ситуацией, над которой очень крепко думал. Давайте рассмотрим ее.

Допустим, в сцене (в игре) имеется система частиц, которая обладает следующими свойствами:

- Все типы частиц наследуются от интерфейса `Particle`;
- Высока вероятность добавления новых типов частиц;
- Допустим, есть такие типы частиц: `Dust`, `Blood`, `Rain`, `Fair`, `Shard`;
- Каждый тип частиц на 90% уникален относительно других типов частиц - отличаются переменные-члены, интерфейс, алгоритм взаимодействия с объектами сцены, а также список объектов, с которыми это взаимодействие происходит;
- По правилам хорошего тона, частица не знает, как она будет отрисовываться, с кем она будет взаимодействовать и прочие подобные вещи.

На мой взгляд, в этом сценарии полиморфизм на основе интерфейса абсолютно не применим. Причина заключается в том, что полиморфизм подтипов через интерфейс предка допустим только в ситуациях, когда потомок сам себя обрабатывает. То есть, когда у потомка есть вся необходимая информация для обработки.

Например, каждая конкретная сцена может сама себя обработать, потому что взаимодействие в основном происходит с тем, что содержится в самой сцене. Поэтому, мы можем управлять любой сценой через обобщенный интерфейс вида: `react(event)`, `draw(render)`, `process(dt)`.

С системой частиц ситуация обстоит точно противоположная. У частицы нет информации о том, где она находится и с чем ей нужно взаимодействовать. Поэтому, система частиц не способна управлять частицами через обобщенный интерфейс.

Вернее, это возможно, но я не понимаю, для чего все эти сложности.

Иногда я поражаюсь, что в коде начинают использоваться крайне запутанные решения на основе того же паттерна проектирования `Посетитель`(`Visitor`). Когда я спрашиваю, зачем это было сделано, мне говорят, что это правильно, а вот использование `dynamic_cast` - это неправильно.

Самое интересное заключается в том, что если в коде использовать `dynamic_cast`, то код становится понятнее, короче и гибче.

Более того, в некоторых особенно требовательных ко скорости случаях можно вообще обойтись без полиморфизма. Например, использовать обертку, которая хранит `ID` типа и `void*`. Тогда вся магия будет происходит лишь в двух местах: в точке доступа к объекту через обертку и в точке обработки объекта, который сокрыт под оберткой.

Объясните мне, пожалуйста, неужели тонны запутанного кода на основе посетителей чем-то лучше, чем использование `dynamic_cast`-а или его самописного аналога?

Comment: *"Самое интересное заключается в том, что если в коде использовать dynamic_cast, то код становится понятнее, короче и гибче."* - код в студию...

Comment: Вообще-то сила ООП - в том, что можно использовать код некоторой функции, написанной тогда, когда никто и не подозревал о том, для каких объектов она будет применяться. `dynamic_cast` портит самое главное - при ее применении изменения надо вносить в несколько мест!

Comment: @Mikhailo, а при использовании посетителя изменения нужно вносить в еще большее количество мест.

Comment: @user7860670, привести код не могу, потому что он является коммерческим. Разве вам недостаточно приведенного в вопросе примера? Вы утверждаете, что полиморфизм через базовый интерфейс способен решить поставленную задачу лучше, чем использование `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: @MGNeo, без кода не особо понятно, как именно ты собираешься использовать `dynamic_cast` вместо посетителя... нагородишь кучу `if else`'ов?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, по вашему `switch()` чем-то отличается от кучи `if else`? Чем `switch()` хуже, чем дополнительная иерархия классов для реализации посетителя?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, к тому же посетитель предназначен для добавления новых операций к имеющимся объектам, а не для добавления новых объектов и новых операций одновременно.

Comment: @MGNeo при чём тут `switch`? а отличается хотя бы в том, что производительность у условных переходов куда хуже, чем у вызовов через vtable... да и если оно необходимо более, чем в одном месте, то порево из оных будет расползаться и почти наверняка будет вызывать скрытые ошибки при добавлении объектов, а посетитель просто откажется компилироваться пока всё не исправишь...

Comment: @MGNeo, да, нормального способов и добавлять новые операции и новые объекты — нет... если первое происходит часто — используй посетителя, если второе — просто добавь операцию к классу... если ни то ни другое делать не хочется, то всегда можно пожаловаться на свою тяжёлую жизнь в каком-нить чатике...

Comment: *"У частицы нет информации о том, где она находится и с чем ей нужно взаимодействовать. Поэтому, система частиц не способна управлять частицами через обобщенный интерфейс."* Вот это не понял. Раз у частиц есть какой-нибудь `virtual void Update();`, то можно ему в параметры передавать ссылки на все необходимое.

Comment: *"приведенного в вопросе примера"* - в вопросе пример отсутствует.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, у частицы нет и не должно быть никакого `Update()`. Частица предоставляет интерфейс для изменения своего внутреннего состояния, не более. Частица не должна знать о существовании окружающего мира, о правилах взаимодействия с объектами и о правилах отрисовки.

Comment: @user7860670, привер присутствует. Он написан на русском языке.

Comment: пример - это как [mcve], а не расплывчатые описания

Comment: Тогда можете показать небольшой пример, как вы это делаете с visitor-ом, и с dynamic_cast-ом?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, написать пример смогу, но сейчас сделать это возможности нет.

Comment: по тексту вопроса невозможно дать осмысленный ответ

Comment: @MGNeo Возможность все еще не появилась?

Answer (score -2):

Когда используется dinamic_cast, то в поля всей иерархии классов добавляется "поле типа". Это не есть хорошо с точки зрения оверхеда. Возможно, что некоторые задачи не могут быть выражены только с помощью нисходящего проектирования. И тогда надо применять dinamic_cast. Но надо понимать, что там есть оверхед и что он занимает время и память.

UPD1:

Скорее всего dinamic_cast не является ЖИЗНЕННО необходимым элементом. Об этом можно судить хотя бы потому, что в многочисленных учебниках по С++ отсутствует дежурный пример, который иллюстрировал бы случай, когда без dinamic_cast невозможно обойтись. Отсюда делаем вывод, что dinamic_cast это костыли, и при правильном проектировании иерархии классов без dinamic_cast вполне можно обойтись.

Но иногда, когда разработка зашла уже слишком далеко, и вдруг появляются новые вводные, перепроектирование иерархии классов может быть слишком дорогим удовольствием. И тогда приходится прибегать к dinamic_cast.

Comment: мне кажется, что Вы никогда не использовали `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Я никогда не ездил на слоне (не использовал динамик каст). Имел в любви большие неудачи. Страна не пожалеет обо мне. Но обо мне товарищи заплачут.

Comment: мне кажется, что "поле типа" добавляется в полиморфные объекты независимо от использования динамик_каст, полиморфизм то должен работать)

Comment: @goldstar_labs По моим понятиям, в современных компиляторах RTTI можно выключить в настройках компилятора и тогда "поле типа" не будет добавляться. И, соответственно, не будет оверхеда. Когда-то давно, когда С++ только начинался, никакого динамик-каст-а в С++ не было. Как раз потому, что это вызывает оверхед. А потом Страуструп прогнулся под реальную жизнь (не стоит прогибаться под изменчивый мир кстати) и пошло-поехало. Короче, это все придумал Черчиль в восемнадцатом году.

Answer (score -2):

Не знаю почему вдруг `dynamic_cast` стал плохой практикой, так как все зависит от задачи, которую необходимо решить.

Представим, что вы разрабатываете программное обеспечение от которого зависят жизни людей и используете полиморфизм с приведением типов. В данном случае следует использовать проверенный и надежный алгоритм, проверенный миллионами людей, а не самописный. Здесь `dynamic_cast` вне конкуренции, а любая другая реализация его замещающая не только непрофессиональна, но может даже и преступна.

Если вы разрабатываете программное обеспечение от которого не зависят жизни людей и оно критично к производительности. При этом нарушение его работы меньшее зло чем скорость, тогда [довольно тяжеловесный `dynamic_cast`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/dyncast.cc) может оказаться препятствием для достижения цели. В этом случае вполне допустимо его замещение на что-то более производительное.

Отсюда ответ на Ваш вопрос. Используйте `dynamic_cast` где есть высокие требования к безопасности и замещайте его где есть высокие требования к производительности.

[Здесь](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c146-use-dynamic_cast-where-class-hierarchy-navigation-is-unavoidable) содержаться некоторые рекомендации для случая когда хождение по иерархии нельзя избежать, более предпочтительные варианты и исключения.

Comment: А пояснения к минусу будут ?

Comment: я не ставил минус, но интересно на что вы предлагаете заменить динамик_каст в местах с повышенными требованиями к производительости?

Comment: я не ставил минус, но: "проверенность" алгоритма миллионами людей не означает надежности. (Важна верифицируемость, и простота проверки, в том числе по формальным правилам.) MISRA не рекомендует использовать dynamic_cast в mission-critile коде. см. правило 5-2-3 MISRA-cpp-2008  http://frey.notk.org/books/MISRA-Cpp-2008.pdf

Comment: минусы и не мои тоже... но они могут быть, например, из-за того, что разработка ПО «от которого зависят жизни людей» и usecase'ы `dynamic_cast`'а связаны чуть больше, чем **ни как**...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Так там и С++ тогда больше чем никак может быть. Написано же в случае использования, зачем передергивать?

Comment: @Chorkov ""проверенность" алгоритма миллионами людей не означает надежности." - это здравый смысл. Часть функциональности компилятора, который используется большим количеством пользователей однозначно лучше уникального самодела. MISRA рекомендует не использовать такое приведение типа, но раз уж вы его используете, а еще хуже, пытаетесь изобрести велосипед то этого уж точно не нужно делать.

Comment: @goldstar_labs Я вообще то предлагаю не изобретать велосипед, где это не нужно, А вот если вам это потребовалось то делать это только при крайней необходимости.